# CSS how to put one div vertically under another within a container div

Tags: css

I have a container div and I would like to put two other divs inside it.  I've seen a lot of examples but they seem to be doing side by side. I can't use anything but pure css.  There are actually a couple of other settings to make this compatible with all mobile devices as well and center all the content.

So far what I have tried which gets close is what's below and the result right now is that the subsection is embedded within the section div and centered in it.  I need the subsection to sit under the section div while still keep the contents of the section div scrollable.

```
.container{
   display:flex
   height:inherit
   position:relative
}

.section{
   overflow:auto
   height:100%
   position:absolute
}

.subsection{
   position:absolute
}

<div class="container">
   <div class="section"></div>
   <div class="subsection"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could remove all your CSS and get the result you want but I feel there's something more you actually want. Could you please better describe the result you want?

Comment: More details added.

Answer (score 0):

By default one div will occupy one line, you can just write code like this

```
<div>
    <div>up div</div>
    <div>down div</div>
</div>
```

the down div will under up div, no extra css is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy. Refer JSFIDDLE created for you. Change css like (Image is added to show an example as div is rarely empty :D )

css

```
.container{
  /* float: left; */
  display: block;
  width: 30%;

}
.section {
  height: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
}
.abs {
  position: absolute;
}
.rel {
  position: relative;
}
.slider img {
    width: 100%;
}

.subsection{
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="section rel">
    <p>
      # RELATIVE SLIDER
    </p>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x50"  />
  </div>
  <div class="subsection rel">
    <p>
      # RELATIVE CONTENT
    </p>
    sample text
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uorgj4e1/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish what I needed by putting `.subSection{Position:fixed; bottom:0}`.

That kept the subsection `div` fixed to the bottom of the page while the section `div` still scrolls.